# MySQL - RENAME column to enable INSERT derived table into another derived table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to combine two derived tables (each through several joins).  The resulting two tables have all the same columns, except one that needs to be renamed to enable one table being inserted into the other.

-> INSERT INTO < DerivedTable1 > < DerivedTable2 >

---> DerivedTable1.ActualPostedDate == DerivedTable2.StartDate

How can I rename DerivedTable2.StartDate to DerivedTable2.ActualPostedDate to enable the insert?

```
INSERT INTO
SELECT
    saleDetails.ActualPostedDate,
    saleDetails.MasterCust,
    saleDetails.ProdName,
    saleDetails.QtySold,
    distributorPricing.item_name,
    distributorPricing.package_name,
    distributorPricing.fob_price,
    distributorPricing.volume_gal,
    distributorPricing.volume_ce,
    customerDetails.Chain,
    customerDetails.Premise,
    customerDetails.Channel,
    customerDetails.Territory
FROM saleDetails
LEFT JOIN distributorPricing USING (ProdName)
LEFT JOIN customerDetails USING (MasterCust)
ORDER BY ActualPostedDate) AS DerivedTable1
SELECT 
    saleDetails_other.StartDate,
    saleDetails_other.MasterCust,
    saleDetails_other.ProdName,
    saleDetails_other.QtySold,
    distributorPricing_other.item_name,
    distributorPricing_other.package_name,
    distributorPricing_other.fob_price,
    distributorPricing_other.volume_gal,
    distributorPricing_other.volume_ce,
    customerDetails_other.Chain,
    customerDetails_other.Premise,
    customerDetails_other.Channel,
    customerDetails_other.Territory
FROM saleDetails_other
LEFT JOIN distributorPricing_other USING (ProdName)
LEFT JOIN customerDetails_other USING (MasterCust)) AS DerivedTable2;
```

Comment: You can't insert into a derived table , backtrack a bit and describe the problem you are trying to solve (rather than your posited solution)

Comment: Thanks, I can do that. 
I have two sets of data.  They are sales data from two sources and i would like to look at them together.  These two data sets are a combination of three joined tables each.  The issue is that one column ( the date) differ in name.  So when combining them, i need the names to match to have the columns line up in the final table.